# Activity stopped after called new intent without finish() in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

When I called new intent in an activity for picking image using `startActivityForResult()`,

but app is stopped after pick photo from gallery,
may be the activity stopped after call new intent.

```
    Intent image_pick_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    image_pick_intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(image_pick_intent, Request.REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK);
```

I didn't face this problem with same code before, any idea why I have triggered this and how can I go back to OnActivityResult of the activity after image pick?

Thank You :)

Comment: where is onActivityResult()

Comment: error log please

Comment: Are you sure onActivityResult(...) is never being called?

Comment: Yes, I added breakpoint so I have confirmed that onAcitivtyResult(...) is never being called. Thank you.

Comment: @PrashantJaiswal There is no error or crash occurred, thats why I think there is something wrong when I called the intent. Thanks.

Comment: Am I missing things in manifest so the previous activity is cleared after open new activity?

Comment: Please post your relevant code as well

Comment: I am sorry that I mistakenly put android:noHistory="true" in the AndroidManifest under this activity, problem is solved after remove this, thank you very much for all of you helping me. Thank you!

Comment: code seems to be ok but need whole code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which os version you are running on?
Have you checked your permission to access based on os version?
Check manifest as well.

Comment: I have granted for the permission and same situation in devices with Android 4.3, 5, 6 and 7. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry that I mistakenly put android:noHistory="true" in the AndroidManifest under this activity, problem is solved after remove this, thank you very much for all of you helping me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

first of all download [photoutil.jar](https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil/blob/master/PhotoUtil.jar) and paste in project->apps->libs.

```
final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 22131;


startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
            String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
            selectedPhoto = photoPath;
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).getBitmap();
                imgProof.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Something Wrong while choosing photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```